# derivative of $t^{-1} - t$ when $t =9$

Tags: calculus

[image]

I'm using the quotient law $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ to find it but I'm having some trouble.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: derivative is $\lim\limits_{h\to0}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$; do you know the formula for the derivative of $t^n$ with respect to $t$?

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: If you remember $\dfrac d{dt} t^n=nt^{n-1} , n\ne0$, that's easier than the limit

Comment: Hold on I am solving

Comment: I haven't used this notation by the way. How would I start?.

Comment: Use @J.W.Tanner's hint.

Comment: in other notation, if $f(x)=x^n$, then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}, n\ne0$; and you can use the derivative sum rule to say if $f(x)=x^n+x^m$ then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}+mx^{m-1}, mn\ne0$

Comment: ok so I am getting f(x) = -1(9)^-2 - 1 . sorry if the format is a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need quotient law. The derivative of $t^{-1}$ is $-(t^{-2})$. The derivative of $-t$ is equal to $-1$.. Put this together and the derivative is $-t^{-2}-1$.

Now plug in $9=t$ to get  $\frac{-1}{81}-1$

Answer (score 0):

This formula:
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Is not the quotient rule as you say. It represents the rate of change not the function derivative. The derivative requires using limits:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=f'\left(x\right)=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}\right)$$

This is usually complex to calculate, instead there are some rules for common forms.

[image: Basic derivative rules - Source: UC-Davis].

Back to your question - Given:
$$f(t)=t^{-1}-t$$

$$f'(t)= (t^{-1})' - (1) \tag1$$

$$(1)'=0$$
$$t^{-1}=\frac{1}{t}$$

Applying "Quotient Rule":
$$(t^{-1})'=(\frac{1}{t})'=\frac{0\times t-(t)'(1)}{t^2}=\frac{-1}{t^{2}}$$

Using (1):
$$f'(t)= \frac{-1}{t^{2}}-1$$

Now,
$$f'(9)=\frac{-1}{81}-1.$$